# Drupal: modify default homepage to strip html from nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have nodes being displayed as 'promoted to homepage'. The nodes body can contain basic html which is fine for that nodes page but when not for the homepage. Is there any way to modify this to strip any html tags?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to handle this would be to just replace the default home page with a view from the Views module.

Just create a view to list nodes (title/body/post date/whatever), filter by "promote to front page", and check the "strip html" checkbox for the body field.

Comment: This is definitely the most elegant solution. The default drupal homepage is not supposed to suit everyones needs, it is just a placeholder. Views is perfect for creating pages like this

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in the theme template. In your theme folder, create or edit node.tpl.php. What it will need to look like will depend on what specifically your node template contains, but with the default template it would be something like this:

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print $user_picture; ?>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $node_title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted || !empty($content['links']['terms'])): ?>
    <div class="meta">
      <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
        <span class="submitted">
          <?php
            print t('Submitted by !username on !datetime',
              array('!username' => $name, '!datetime' => $date));
          ?>
        </span>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if (!empty($content['links']['terms'])): ?>
        <div class="terms terms-inline"><?php print render($content['links']['terms']); ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      if ($is_front) {
        print strip_tags(render($content));
      } else {
        print render($content);
      }
      ?>
  </div>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

</div>
```

Note, I haven't tested this at all, but if your theme is using the default node template (there is no node.tpl.php in your theme), then you should be able to just drop this in.

The key line is:

```
      if ($is_front) {
        print strip_tags(render($content));
      } else {
        print render($content);
      }
```